# Aws integration spring: Guarantee only one item from sqs

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am trying to only allow one item from an sqs queue being worked on at a given time. Currently it will only lift a single message of a queue but it will keep doing this at what seems to be every time it polls.

```
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
      executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
      executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
      executor.setQueueCapacity(10);
      executor.setThreadNamePrefix("test-");
      executor.initialize();
      return executor;

      new SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(amazon));
      adapter.setMaxNumberOfMessages(1);
      adapter.setSendTimeout(2000);
      adapter.setVisibilityTimeout(1200);
      adapter.setWaitTimeOut(20);
      adapter.setTaskExecutor(this.asyncTaskExecutor());
```

The problem seems to be within the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor and my understanding of this. As the queue size is 10 will it lift every time until this is full?

Setting the maxPoolSize to 1. Causes an

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$SignalExecutingRunnable@406354e5 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@30d53b7[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2047)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1369)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:293)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your ThreadPoolExecutor is set to have a BlockingQueue size of 10 using 2 threads to consume messages off this queue.  So at any given time you can have 2 threads working on messages simultaneously.  If you set the PoolSize to 1 then you can guarantee that only one message will be worked on at a given time.

From the source code:

```
/*
 * Proceed in 3 steps:
 *
 * 1. If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, try to
 * start a new thread with the given command as its first
 * task.  The call to addWorker atomically checks runState and
 * workerCount, and so prevents false alarms that would add
 * threads when it shouldn't, by returning false.
 *
 * 2. If a task can be successfully queued, then we still need
 * to double-check whether we should have added a thread
 * (because existing ones died since last checking) or that
 * the pool shut down since entry into this method. So we
 * recheck state and if necessary roll back the enqueuing if
 * stopped, or start a new thread if there are none.
 *
 * 3. If we cannot queue task, then we try to add a new
 * thread.  If it fails, we know we are shut down or saturated
 * and so reject the task.
```

You are hitting the third case.

Comment: This my first idea this did not work see above. @Gandalf

Comment: Will probably need a lot more of the code to figure this out.  GitHub?